# how to setup 'bootstrap tour' in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

i used bootstrap-tour.min.css and bootstrap-tour.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='bootstrap-tour.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-tour.min.css">
```

This is my view page

```
<form>
    <input id="one" value="one" />
    <input id="two" value="two" />
</form>
```

and this is my js file

```
// Instance the tour
$(function () {
    var tour = new Tour();
    tour.addStep({
        element: "#one",
        title: "Step 1",
        content: "Content for step 1"
    });

    tour.addStep({
        element: "#two",
        title: "Step 1",
        content: "Content for step 1"
    });

    // Initialize the tour
    tour.init();

    // Start the tour
    tour.start();

});
// tour end
```

but still tour not working.. anyone help me:( !...

Comment: How about you check this out instead of doing it your way?

https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-tour-rails/versions/0.4.0

gem, bundle, woila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to ask some questions back, hopefully they already help you.

What error message are you getting (if any?)
I think bootstrap-tour relies on bootstrap, did you setup that?
Did you make use of application.js / application.css? Or application.css.scss in case you use the bootstrap-sass gem?

Are you using the gem 'boostrap-tour-rails', or are you including plain css?

Comment: thanks kjell,i required both application.css and application.js..now i will try bootstrap-tour-rails gem :)

Comment: Um... by 'require both application.css...' did you mean you included them in your view page? That should not be necessary, rails does that for you.

Comment: just leave it kjell..now i used  'boostrap-tour-rails' gem..but i have application.scss..when i add  '*= require bootstrap-tour' , i got error..like a 'Sprockets::FileNotFound'